# Creating a case-insensitive dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the application I'm writing I have a dictionary with a key named "Name". A user will then input text into a UITextField object then I insert the textField.text into a function that searches the JSON dictionary for that value for the key "Name". **The problem I have** is if the user types in "tyler" and the value in the JSON file is "Tyler" that value isn't retrieved. Also the JSON file is of type:

```
[String: AnyObject]
```

What is the best way to ensure case insensitivity with this in mind?

Thanks

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Just do a case-insensitive comparison of the values.

Comment: I think you should save your dictionary keys all lowercase and just use "ANYKEY".lowercaseString to retrieve the key value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change your dictionary to

```
[String : (String,AnyObject)]
```

This way you could store the lowercase (or all uppercase) "key" in as the key, and then your tuple could have the actual spelling (if this matters) and the `AnyObject` as the 2nd item of the tuple.